# Where to deploy a Python Flask-SocketIO Webapp

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, socket.io

I'd like to create a Python web app with Flask-SocketIO and I found [this example](https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask) which I'm studying. To test the outcome, I'd like to deploy that script online and see how it acts after being deployed.

Would it be possible to deploy it? What's the best way or place of deploying this kind of app? I tried to host it on Heroku but I had a lot of problems during the process, so I was looking for an alternative way.

Comment: _on Heroku but I had a lot of problems during the process_ [Heroku even have a guide for a Flask app with sockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets).

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socketio attaches to your flask app as a [middleware](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This means that, while there may be deployment issues specific to socketio, you should be able to deploy anywhere that a typical flask app can. You already saw the heroku docs in the comments, and these are the flask deployment docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/